# Console Log Result And Typing the result is different

Tags: javascript, mysql, discord, discord.js

When I run this Javascript code that selects the id where the username is admin.

```
conauth.connect(function(err) {
 if (err) throw err;
  conauth.query("SELECT id FROM account WHERE username = (?)",[object], function (err, result, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(result)
    message.reply(result)
  });
});
```

The Console result is Correct

> [ RowDataPacket { id: 8 } ]

But the message reply ( on discord ) returns :

> @JADA, [object Object]

I Only Want the actual result which is 8 as a number only.

Comment: does `message.reply(result.id)` not work?

Comment: @damonholden it returns undefined

Comment: @damonholden I just tested it for console and it gives Undefined but on discord the result is Empty

Comment: what does `console.log(result.length)` return?

Comment: @damonholden returns 1

Comment: try `message.reply(result[0].id)`

Comment: DID WORK, thank you! - Please add it as answer so i can vote it up!

Comment: no worries at all, glad to help.

Comment: @damonholden I was wondering, I'm trying now to get ( random multiple results and using 0 - 1 - 2 won't work as it's randomized ) do you have any suggestions ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250323/discussion-between-damonholden-and-jada-developer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this situation, `result` is an array with a single object value that contains an `id` property.

To return just the id property of the object, use this:

```
message.reply(result[0].id) // 8
```

`result[0]` targets the first value in the array and `.id` targets the `id` property of that value.

Hope this helps.